# Convert to python TimeField object

Tags: python, django

I have been googling around but surprisingly haven't seen what I was looking for.

I have strings like these

```
    '11:00 am',
    '12:00 pm',
```

How does one convert this to Django models.TimeField() object.

Comment: You mean, create?

Comment: Yes, convert to Django models TimeField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TimeField corresponds to a `datetime.time` object in python (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#timefield), so the value has to be converted into a `time`. This can be done through `datetime.datetime.strptime()` and then converted to a time, like

```
t = datetime.datetime.strptime("11:34 am", "%I:%M %p").time()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Django TimeField()` takes a `Datetime.time()` object as input so you can do the following:

Convert them to a time object using `datetime.time()` and `datetime.strptime()` then pass them to the model.

```
from datetime import datetime    

datetime.time(datetime.strptime('11:00 am', '%I:%M %p'))
#datetime.time(11, 0)

datetime.time(datetime.strptime('11:00 pm', '%I:%M %p'))
#datetime.time(23, 0)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#timefield)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a model as

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    my_time_field = models.TimeField()
```

You can create the model instance with time field as

1. Using the `create()` method

```
instance = Foo.objects.create(my_time_field="11:00 am")
```

2. Using `save()` method

```
instance = Foo(my_time_field="11:00 am")
instance.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('11:00 am', "%I:%M %p").time()
```